# Crawl data from an html table in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a beginner in web crawling and I need help in getting the values from the table. I have got all the required fields (LOCATION,DATE,SUMMARY,DEADLINE). What I want is the Summary is having a url to another page. I want that url to get appended along with the other fields like (LOCATION,DATE,SUMMARY,DEADLINE,***URL***)

[This is the website](https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders.php)

This is my code so far. But its not working

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders-{}.php'

amount_of_pages = 2 #5194 
rows = []

for i in range(1,amount_of_pages):
    response = rq.get(url.format(i))


    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table',{'id':'datatable'})

        headers = []

        for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
           headers.append(th.text.strip())

        for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            cells = []
            tds = tr.find_all("td")

            if len(tds) == 0:
                ths = tr.find_all("th")

                for th in ths:
                    cells.append(th.text.strip())
            else:
                for td in tds:
                    cells.append(td.text.strip())
                    cells.append('https://www.tendersinfo.com/' + td.find('a')['href'])

            rows.append(cells)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working?

Comment: i cannot extract the required fields from the table LOCATION | DATE |SUMMARY |DEADLINE are my required fields

Comment: @BibinBinny, you are using a wrong url u will need to use this ```https://www.tendersinfo.com/ajax_all_new_search.php?country=information-technology&increment=1&%20select=500&%20total=259655&%20search_id=19906&%20order=id&%20imagevalue=1```

Comment: update increment value as u progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I just re-coded the majority of it.

```py
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

location = []
posted_date = []
summary = []
deadline = []

url = 'https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders-{}.php'

amount_of_pages = 10 # Max is 5194 currently
rows = []

for i in range(1,amount_of_pages):
    response = rq.get(url.format(i))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table',{'id':'datatable'})
        headers = []
        for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
           headers.append(th.text.strip())
        for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            cells = []
            tds = tr.find_all("td")
            if len(tds) == 0:
                ths = tr.find_all("th")
                for th in ths:
                    cells.append(th.text.strip())
            else:
                for td in tds:
                    cells.append(td.text.strip())
            rows.append(cells)

pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers).to_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web Scraping (RFP's)\RFP_SCRAPED_DATA.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i need. But I collects only a few records, there are thousands more I want all of them. Please help

Comment: @BibinBinny I believe I fixed it. Be careful scraping that much all at once though because that is a lot of stress on their servers.

Comment: This works perfectly man. I would like to get the urls of each summary from all the pages. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Since your using pandas, why not use [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) which return's extracted tables as a list of DataFrames.

```
>>> tables = pd.read_html("https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders.php")

>>> tables[1]

  LOCATION         DATE                                        SUMMARY     DEADLINE
0    India  21-May-2020  Liquid Crystal Display Lcd Panel Or Monitors.  01-Jun-2020
1    India  21-May-2020                          Random Access Memory.  01-Jun-2020
2    India  21-May-2020         Supply Of Analog Transceiver-handheld.  01-Jun-2020
3    India  21-May-2020                   Supply Of Computer Printers.  01-Jun-2020
4    India  21-May-2020                                 All In One Pc.  01-Jun-2020
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the table easily using `pd.read_html` and save this data into `csv` file using `df.to_csv()`.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.tendersinfo.com/ajax_all_new_search.php?country=information-technology&increment=1&%20select=500&%20total=259655&%20search_id=19906&%20order=id&%20imagevalue=1"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

df.to_csv("RFP_SCRAPED_DATA.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: only 50 records are collected here I want all the ***259655***  records

Comment: @BibinBinny updated my code.increment value as you progress